# Identify User's Email Address From Gmail API Inbox Action

Tags: inbox, gmail-api, google-schemas

Is there a way to simply identify and return the user's email address from an INBOX ACTION.

E.G

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "ConfirmAction",
  "name": "My Birthday Party",
  ... information about the event ...
  "action": {
    "@type": "RsvpAction",
    "actionHandler": {
      "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
      "url": "https://mysite.com/rsvp?email_address=USERS'S EMAIL ADDRESS HERE",
      "method": "POST",
      "requiredProperty": "rsvpStatus",
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

All the users our organization use a Gmail Account so there is no need to generate an additional identifier in place of "email_address=USERS'S EMAIL ADDRESS HERE" shown in the link above since we already have their email addresses on file.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you authenticating using IMAP or a client_secret.json ?

Comment: Thanks Stormie. We are using a client secret via Oauth2 authentication

Comment: Could you clarify the question for me please? I don't understand which email address you want. Is it the sender's email address?

Comment: Thanks again for the response. In this case we are sender, the recipient is the email address we want. Under normal circumstances, we would have an identifier to identify the email address of the person who clicked on the link in the inbox action. In this case we would like to simply send a group email to various users to reduce the overhead on the system, then identify user when he/she clicks on the Inbox Action button in the Gmail Inbox. See https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/reference/go-to-action for info on Inbox actions if needed.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with schemas to be much help, I'm sorry. :(

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't supported. You would either need to set that email address parameter when you send the email or use a limited-use access token as described here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/actions/limited-use-access-tokens

Comment: Thank you. In the case of limited use access tokens we would still need to save the generated access token against the users info we have on file which is generally how we have done it in the past. Was wondering if inbox actions could help us skip that step, but it seems there is no way to do that. Greatly appreciate the response.